# MUI-X data grid exports empty rows instead of content

Tags: material-ui, mui-datatable

When clicking on the export button, some rows are empty in the exported CSV file.

Here is a sample content of the DataGrid:
[image: gridcontent]

Here is the exported CSV:
[image: csvresult]

As you can see, all rows are exported in columns 2-5, but under the first column, only three are exported. The rest is empty.
Link to live example: https://tineye-next.vercel.app/

Answer (score 0):

The issue was on my side. For some reason, the URLs stored in firestore start with \n, and the data exported, but I could not see the value because of the control character.